# Getting all nodes, values and the node attributes from an undefined XML

Tags: c#, xml

So, this seems very tricky for some reason. I think I have tried every solution I can think of but none seem to be coming close to the result I require.

Say I have a custom XML. It is unstructured but has a common "schema" i.e:

```
<holder id="1">
   <name datatype="int">First Record</name>
   <cost datatype="double">100.24</cost>
   <service datatype="string" serviceID="12345">A custom service</service>
</holder>


<holder id="2">
   <name datatype="int">secondRecord</name>
   <cost datatype="double">3000.24</cost>
   <service datatype="string" serviceID="9876">A custom service 2</service>
</holder>
```

all I want to do is go through all of this and parse it into my custom class files.
I have a custom Xml Node (properties: Name (i.e "Cost", value i.e "100.24")
I have a collection of attributes (key/valuepair) in the custom xml Node class

Any ideas how to parse this xml?

Comment: XmlReader, XmlSerializer, take your pick, show what you tried so far instead of saying you tried every solution you can think of...

Comment: well ive deleted most of the tries so nothing to report there or get confused about. my intentions are pretty clear here. XmlSerializer will not work here for a start....

Comment: well, what is unclear to me, is currently what is failing? Or what you are trying to do with it? Some way you have to create the mapping? How does your key/valuepair custom xml class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could go for a simple Tree system to read your Xml, it doesn't have to know anything about the XML, can set attributes with an Item indexer, or by using some methods, and using the XmlReader you can go through the node quite fast yourself

However, from my comments you could also see that to me, your problem wasn't completely clear (what you have tried, what is failing, what should be the end result)

I have set up some classes that create a Tree, can register some properties (ITreeNode), have a parent and have a child (i am guessing, as this part of your post is also missing, that it is something a like your custom XmlNode)

Basically, this is the custom XmlParser

```
public class TreeNodeParser
{
    public T ReadNode<T>(T parent, XmlReader reader)
        where T: class, ITreeNode, new()
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
        {
            return null;
        }
        T subNode = new T();

        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Read())
        {
        }

        subNode.Tag = reader.Name;
        subNode.Parent = parent;

        if (reader.AttributeCount > 0)
        {
            reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
            do
            {
                subNode.SetAttribute(reader.Name, reader.Value);
            } while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute());
        }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                if (string.Equals(subNode.Tag, reader.Name))
                {
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                T child = ReadNode(subNode, reader);
                if (child != null)
                {
                    subNode.Children.Add(child);
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                subNode.ValueAsString = reader.Value;
                continue;
            }
        }

        return subNode;
    }

    public T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
        where T : class, ITreeNode, new()
    {
        T result = default(T);

        using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T child = ReadNode(result, reader);
                if (child != null)
                {
                    result = child;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You can hand it a stream, which it well read through, reading all elements and all attributes (and ignoring whitespace elements). As an xml is in essence a Tree, you get the rootNode back (if any)

As an example, this is the test main program (console)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TreeNodeParser nodeParser = new TreeNodeParser();
    using (Stream readStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "TestFile.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var node = nodeParser.FromStream<Node>(readStream);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", node.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The implement TreeNode had the following `ToString()` override implemented (so you can see that it's not just reading the value as a string ;)):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string content = "", attributes = "";
    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
        content += child;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ValueAsString))
    {
        content += ValueAsString;
    }
    foreach (var entry in properties)
    {
        attributes += string.Format(" {0}=\"{1}\"", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
    {
        return string.Format("<{0}{2} />", this.Tag, content, attributes);
    }
    return string.Format("<{0}{2}>{1}</{0}>", this.Tag, content, attributes);
}
```

}

which has as a result
[image: Example output of Custom XmlReader]

for this to work, i had to change your basic Xml to the following structure (at least one root element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ValueList>
  <holder id="1">
    <name datatype="int">First Record</name>
    <cost datatype="double">100.24</cost>
    <service datatype="string" serviceID="12345">A custom service</service>
  </holder>
  <holder id="2">
    <name datatype="int">secondRecord</name>
    <cost datatype="double">3000.24</cost>
    <service datatype="string" serviceID="9876">A custom service 2</service>
  </holder>
</ValueList>
```

And a possible interface for the ITreeNode could be something like that (though that shouldn't be necessary with your custom XmlNode, so that part you could refactor in the first piece of code)

```
public interface IPropertyHolder
{
    string this[string attributeName] { get; }
    void SetAttribute(string attribute, string value);
    string GetAttribute(string attribute);
}

public interface INodeParent<T>
{
    IList<T> Children { get; }
}

public interface INodeChild<T>
{
    T Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface INode
{
    string Tag { get; set; }
    string ValueAsString { get; set; }
    object Value { get; }
}

public interface ITreeNode : INode, IPropertyHolder, INodeParent<ITreeNode>, INodeChild<ITreeNode>
{
}
```